# SharePoint link should open in File Explorer but opens in Web Browser

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint

As the name of the question states, I'm working with my company on a project in UiPath that is responsible for scraping a slurry of excel files from a SharePoint server. Unfortunately a decent portion of it is proprietary so I don't know how much of the actual code I can justifiably put here.

I have inside of UiPath (which is essentially a shell for vb.net and C# specifically tailored for automation) functionality to input a website url into the file explorer and have it navigate to the OneDrive folder for that SharePoint site.

This was working as expected until yesterday in the morning when it decided to brick itself and instead pull up the SharePoint site on the web browser.

Is there any way to ensure or otherwise understand *why* it won't open the folder path? I had it working before and I don't know why it doesn't work anymore.

Regards,
Jadda

Comment: Without sample code and sample data it might be hard for anyone to test and replicate the problem.

Comment: It's less a code issue than it is a networking issue.